# SCALA-JSON: How can I manipulate a json to send a json object into 2nd level nested object?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I want to send a main JSON object named `testId` into 2 level nested json objects like the example below (inside `ALTIMETER` and `WEIGHT`). How can i reach the `After Json` below by using `Below Json` in Scala?

In the internet, I saw that I should use json4s jackson library but I really couldn't understand how to use it.
Can you help me with that problem?

Note: The real number of testTags willbe around 1000 and it can be increased day by day that's why I cannot create a case class not to write all of them hardcoded.

Before Json:

```
{
"testId": 123,
"testTags": {
    "ALTIMETER": {
        "result": [
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": "5"
            },
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-18T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": "4"
            }
        ]
    },
    "WEIGHT": {
        "result": [
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": 0.846
            },
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T15:15:13Z",
                "Actual": 0.845
            }
        ]
    }
                }
            }
```

After Json:

```
{
"testId": 123,
"testTags": {
    "ALTIMETER": {
        "testId": 123,
        "result": [
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": "5"
            },
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-18T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": "4"
            }
                ]
            },
    "WEIGHT": {
        "testId": 123
        "result": [
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T12:11:18Z",
                "Actual": 0.846
            },
            {
                "ts": "2023-04-17T15:15:13Z",
                "Actual": 0.845
            }
                ]
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: One approach is to parse the JSON as case class. You don't have to know all items, you can have a `Map[String, MyCaseClass]` at some level.